# capture Order completion status in observer in magento

Tags: magento

Hi I want to catpture the order information when the oder is completed or close.I try different events like (sales_order_place_after) but didn't complete my requirements.I am completing orders form admin side and i create observer for capturing the information like 
Xml :

```
<events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <extra_options>             
                <class>My_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                <method>salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem</method>
            </extra_options>
        </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
```

Observer :

```
public function salesConvertQuoteItemToOrderItem($observer)
    {

        $order = $observer->getOrder();
        $orders = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        if($order->getState() == Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE){
         echo "<pre>";
        print_r($orders);exit;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing everything right except you are listening to wrong event. You have to use `sales_order_save_after` instead.

Comment: This can not work, because you need to check if order status changed, because, the above code would always trigger if you save the order and it has yet been completed.

Answer (score 2):

Using sales_order_save_after is still good, but it just requires you also to check for the state (as Mischa suggests):

```
public function salesOrderSaveAfter($observer)
{       
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    if($order->getState() != Mage_Sales_Model_Order::STATE_COMPLETE) {
        return $this;
    }       

    if($order->getData('state') == $order->getOrigData('state')) {
        return $this;
    }

    // do your stuff

    return $this;
}
```

This works fine for me.